# Not unique in the new ID space | ZK

Tags: zk

I am creating 2 `ListBox` in my Java code using ZK and assigning those `ListBox` unique Ids.This is my flow.

1. Customer select values from the drop box.
2. Hit Save button
3. Values passes to Underlying Service and status got update.
4. We refresh page with help of another event.

Here is how I am creating Listbox

```
Listbox listbox=createListbox(widget,OrderStatus.ORDERSTATUS.class, null,orderStatus);
listbox.setId(ORDER_STATUS_ID);
```

Everything is working fine for the first time, but when I am doing it next time, though underlying code is working fine but I am getting following error message for second time and so on.

```
Not unique in the new ID space: orderStatusId
```

Issue is related to [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186769/zk-window-not-unique-in-id-space) but being new to ZK not sure what can be best way to achieve that.
For me issue seems when We are refreshing page after successful order status update, as code is being executed again and seems it has already that Id assign to it.

### Page Refresh Code

```
 button.addEventListener("onClick", new EventListener()
    {
      public void onEvent(Event event)
        throws Exception
      {
        DetailsWidgetRenderer.this.handleRefreshEvent(widget, event);
      }
    });
```

Comment: How are you refreshing the page in this setup?

Comment: Do you need to know the id of the listbox? 
Do you use a zul page?

Comment: @Yes, I need to have id in order to fetch values of ListBox

Comment: @SeanConnolly: I am using a even for that. Have update my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common mistake when using ZK is to stay in the request/response cycle in your head. ZK doesn't do request/response cycle. Forget about it. ZK is like Swing: You create the UI, you put your data in models and then let the framework render everything.

In your case, you probably try to add the `ListBox` to the UI *again* (because that's what you're used to from JSPs). Don't do that. Just update the models which are attached to the `ListBox` and ZK will refresh the HTML for you.

Comment: Can you guide me how to do that or any link to documents?

Comment: 1. Forget about JSP. 2. Forget about HTML. 3. Get a good book on desktop UI design or remember how you'd write a Swing UI.

Comment: You'll want ZK's "MVC List Model" documentation (rather than their "MVVM Data Binding" documentation): http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/MVC/Model/List_Model